# ASP .Net Rest Api will not update database entry

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, asp.net-core

**Situation:**

I try to update a database entry using REST API. REST API is tested and works with this code:

```
PUT https://[url]/[endpoint]/103 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "cost": 3.49,
    "id": 103,
    "productId": 110,
    "storeId": 5,
    "validFrom": "2020-08-21T00:00:00",
    "validUntil": "0001-01-01 00:00:00"
}
```

**Problem:**

When I try to update it inside the application it does not update (and also does not return any error). The logs show that the object is transfered correctly to the function inside the service.ts.

This is the code I'm using:

component.ts

```
let prePriceUpdate = {} as SavePrice;
this.productService.getProduct(result.productId)
    .subscribe((p: Product) => {
        let prePrice = p.prices.find(p => p.store.id == result.storeId) as Price;
        prePriceUpdate.id = prePrice.id;
        prePriceUpdate.productId = result.productId;
        prePriceUpdate.storeId = prePrice.store.id;
        prePriceUpdate.validFrom = prePrice.validFrom;
        prePriceUpdate.validUntil = moment(result.validFrom).format();
        prePriceUpdate.cost = prePrice.cost;
        this.priceService.update(prePriceUpdate);
});
```

service.ts

```
  update(price: SavePrice){
    return this.http.put(this.pricesEndpoint + '/' + price.id, price)
      .pipe(map(res => res));
  }
```

Any hint where I made the mistake is appreciated.

Comment: Then fire up the debugger and step through the server part to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The logs show that the object is transfered correctly to the function
> inside the service.ts

Yes, but then your service method is not actually sending the `PUT` request. That's because you didn't subscribe to the call.

Add a subscription to the `priceService.update()` call, like -

```
this.productService.getProduct(result.productId)
    .subscribe((p: Product) => {
        // other codes
        this.priceService.update(prePriceUpdate)
            .subscribe(p=> console.log(p));    // subscribe to the call
});
```